# Add element into list at even indexes

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list like

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and I want to add zeroes at odd indexes:

```
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5]
```

My first thought was to create a list with zeroes and replace them with the values from the original list.

```
listOfZeros = [0] * (2*len(list)-1)
    j = 0
    for i in range(0, len(listOfZeros)):
        if (i%2 == 0):
            listOfZeros[i] = h_temp[j]
            j += 1
```

This actually works, but I do dislike for loops and adding another counter j. Isn't there a better way by using slicing?

Answer (score 3):

one way is by using `zip`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
d = [x for t in zip (a, [0] * len(a)) for x in t][:-1]
```

When you use zip, you create list of tuples.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [0,0,0,0,0]
c = zip(a,b)
#zip (a,b) creates [(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(5,0)]
```

Then you loop over the set of tuples to arrange them into list:

```
d = [x for t in c for x in t] #creates [1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0]
```

and cut the last element (since you end with 5)

```
[x for t in c for x in t][:-1] #take out the last 0
#resulting in [1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5]
```

then you are done.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [insert()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_insert.htm). Looking at your output, assuming you are not counting index 0 as even.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
for x in range(len(a)):
    a.insert(2*x+1, 0)
```

Comment: I don't think that inserting into a list of changing length should be recommended. There are better solutions with a generator or with `itertools` (in my opinion at least).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a generator:

```
def zero_on_odd(mylist):
    for i in mylist:
        yield i
        yield 0

a = [1, 2, 3]
with_zeros = list(zero_on_odd(a))[:-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go functional...

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
list(chain(*zip(_list, repeat(0))))[:-1]
# [1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5]
```

If you want to be silly...

```
[int(i) for i in '0'.join(str(i) for i in _list)]
# still [1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5]
```

Or, if you want to be functional AND silly...

```
map(int, '0'.join(map(str, _list)))
# really, it's still [1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5]
# except in Python 3.X, there it's a map object...
```

But, you should probably opt for one of the custom generator solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Another `zip` way:

```
>>> li
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [e for t in  zip(li,[0]*(len(li)-1)) for e in t]+[li[-1]]
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5]
```

You can also use `range` and slice assignment:

```
>>> li=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> for i in range(1,len(li)+len(li)-1, 2): li[i:i]=[0]
... 
>>> li
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5]
```

And, a list comprehension:

```
>>> [li[i/2] if not i%2 else 0 for i in range(len(li)*2-1)]
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of it, here is an `itertools` solution:

```
from itertools import islice, chain

data = [1,2,3,4,5]
print list(islice(chain.from_iterable((x, 0) for x in data), 0, 2 * len(data)-1))
```

Giving:

```
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

A hacky way:

```
>>> ls1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> ls2 = []
>>> list(ls2.extend([n, 0]) for n in ls1)
[None, None, None, None, None]
>>> ls2
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0]
```